# CF Upgrade Issue while binding dropdown value to a bind in cfgrid

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-2018

We are upgrading our CF Server 9 to latest CF 2018. And i am facing bind issue between dropdown selected value and cfgrid bind.

There is dropdown just above the cfgrid that is set  empty at first and has values listed of a query, and just below is a grid that binds the dropdown selection value to the query that is fetched.

At first as empty is selected it would not fetch records and grid would be empty. Also the bind URL is correctly formed.

http://127.0.0.1:8501/app/dummy.cfm?&DbFunc=getRecords&SrcID=&newSrcID=&flt_nm=&flt_iv=&flt_ct=&flt_sc=&flt_in=&pageSize=174&_cf_ajaxproxytoken=6D89B1BFAE8D17997E5A&_cf_clientid=1AFC4F973849FBAE6EAAA465492A0E0B&_cf_rc=0&_cf_nodebug=true&_cf_nocache=true&returnFormat=json&_dc=1549690631545&start=0&limit=174&page=1&sortCol=&sortDir=ASC

But next when i select the dropdownto a new value the URL is formed in this way.

http://127.0.0.1:8501/app/dummy.cfm?&&DbFunc=getRecords&SrcID=Test&SrcID=&&newSrcID=Test&&flt_nm=&&flt_iv=&&flt_ct=&&flt_sc=&&flt_in=&pageSize=174&_cf_ajaxproxytoken=6D89B1BFAE8D17997E5A&_cf_clientid=1AFC4F973849FBAE6EAAA465492A0E0B&_cf_rc=0&_cf_nodebug=true&_cf_nocache=true&returnFormat=json&_dc=1549690634739&start=0&limit=174&page=1&sortCol=&sortDir=ASC

As you can see the SrcID is getting appended twice for first time empty and next adding the selected value. I am receiving this as a comma separated value on my next page which is incorrect.
the query params are getting added as a separate instead of overwiting the old params.

The SrcID param is defined at top and next is the dropdown and directly at the bottom is the cfgrid where it is used in bind.
Thanks in advance

Here is a sample code below

```
<cfajaximport tags="cfform, cfinput-datefield, cftooltip, cfwindow, cfgrid, cfmessagebox">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function doRefresh(form){
    cSrcID = form.SrcID.options[form.SrcID.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log('me'+cSrcID+'u');
    cSortFld = '';
    form.newSrcID.value = cSrcID;
}
// get client area of the browser
var cliWt = getClientWt();  // client width
var cliHt = getClientHt();  // client height

// set grid dimensions scrWidth, scrHeidht
var gWt       = 34;     // right margin
var gHt       = 180;    // top margin
var minWt     = 500;    // min width of the table
var minHt     = 280;    // min height of the table
var scrWidth  = cliWt - gWt;
var scrHeight = cliHt - gHt;
if (scrWidth < minWt) scrWidth = minWt;
if (scrHeight < minHt) scrHeight = minHt;

// set winEdit popup window dimensions
var popwinWt = 1150;
var popwinHt = 680;
var bResizePopup = 0;

if (popwinWt > cliWt) {
    bResizePopup = 1;
    popwinWt = cliWt - 10;
}
if (popwinHt > cliHt) {
    bResizePopup = 1;
    popwinHt = cliHt - 10;
}

// set winEdit2 popup window dimensions
var popwinWt2 = 900;
var popwinHt2 = 510;
var bResizePopup2 = 0;

if (popwinWt2 > cliWt) {
    bResizePopup2 = 1;
    popwinWt2 = cliWt - 10;
}
if (popwinHt2 > cliHt) {
    bResizePopup2 = 1;
    popwinHt2 = cliHt - 10;
}

// set winEdit3 popup window dimensions
var popwinWt3 = 800;
var popwinHt3 = 550;
var bResizePopup3 = 0;

if (popwinWt3 > cliWt) {
    bResizePopup3 = 1;
    popwinWt3 = cliWt - 10;
}
if (popwinHt3 > cliHt) {
    bResizePopup3 = 1;
    popwinHt3 = cliHt - 10;
}


</script>


<cfset maxRowCnt = 174>
<!--- Set Grid default params --->
<cfparam name="page" default="1">
<cfparam name="pageSize" default="#maxRowCnt#">
<cfparam name="cfgridsortcolumn" default="">
<cfparam name="cfgridsortdirection" default="">

<cfform name="mainForm">

    <cfoutput>
        <br /><cfselect name="SrcID" title="Select a Source" style="width:200px;" onchange="doRefresh(this.form)">
                <option value="">Select a Data Source</option>
                <option value="Test">Test</option>
        </cfselect>
    <input type="hidden" name="newSrcID"        value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="flt_nm"  value=""  />
    <input type="hidden" name="flt_iv"  value=""  />
    <input type="hidden" name="flt_ct"  value=""  />
    <input type="hidden" name="flt_sc"  value=""  />
    <input type="hidden" name="flt_in"  value=""  />
    </cfoutput>

    <!--- Main Grid title="List of Records"  --->
    <cfgrid format="html" name="mainGrid" sort="yes"  style="border:1px solid ##002D96;" visible="no" pagesize="#maxRowCnt#" maxrows="#maxRowCnt#" vspace="20"
        striperows="yes" striperowcolor="#gcGray#" bgcolor="#gcRowWhite#" colheaderbold="yes" colheadertextcolor="##464646" width="scrWidth" height="scrHeight"
        selectcolor="##FFCC99" selectmode="edit" selectonload="false" picturebar="yes" gridlines="yes" autowidth="yes"
        bind="url:dummy.cfm?DbFunc=getRecords&SrcID={SrcID}&newSrcID={newSrcID}&flt_nm={flt_nm}&flt_iv={flt_iv}&flt_ct={flt_ct}&flt_sc={flt_sc}&flt_in={flt_in}&page={cfgridpage}&pageSize={cfgridpagesize}&sortCol={cfgridsortcolumn}&sortDir={cfgridsortdirection}"
        onchange="url:dummy.cfm?DbFunc=doNothing&action={cfgridaction}&row={cfgridrow}&changed={cfgridchanged}"
        font="arial" fontsize="14px" colheaderfont="arial" colheaderfontsize="14px" textcolor="##464646">

        <cfgridcolumn name="si_id"          header="ID"         display="yes" select="no" width="45"/> <!--- FDB-164  --->

    </cfgrid>
</cfform>
```

On the dummy.cfm

returns a query data in JSON format based on the Src Id selected

Comment: If you spend more than a couple hours on this, you might be better off migrating your front end UI elements away from ColdFusion. It’s a winning strategy in the long run to avoid using CF for client side UI.

Comment: Please post a working example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Ageax Updated the code with question

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of "query data in JSON format" returned by dummy.cfm? That would make it the grid a lot easier to test.

Comment: ... though I agree with Redtopia. Since it looks like you've had a few issues with upgrading the UI components, at this point it's probably quicker to just switch to another lib that you can control yourself.